# Unable to upload local repository to GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh

Forgive me if I worded the title wrong,
I am an absolute beginner to git, and I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWYqp7iY_Tc.

For software I am using MINGW64.

Everything was sucessful and I created a GitHub repository, but once I tried the command: `$ git push -u origin master`, I received the error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Next, I searched the internet and found that I needed to create an ssh key and upload it to GitHub. I successful completed that, and confirmed that I uploaded the correct key to my profile. After trying again, it still did not work. I am at a loss of what could possibly be wrong.

For specifics and since I am a beginner, here are the commands I used and the process I went through while creating and adding the ssh key.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com" //not my real email btw
//I then entered a passphrase
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

//I then proceed to add this to my GitHub profile:

$ clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
//I then went to the section called "SSH and GPG keys", gave the new key a title, and copied to clip.
```

Again, the above was unsuccessful, and I am wondering if anyone has another method or suggestions to fix this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Use `git remote -v` to confirm whether you have set the remote correctly for your local repository.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I got this back, `$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:thomasbuckley/myappsample.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:thomasbuckley/myappsample.git (push)
`

Comment: It seems you are use ssh to access github. For ssh connection, you should check your ~/.ssh/config for host configuration, I think.

Comment: Is there an alternative to ssh? If so, how would I utilize that vs ssh.

Comment: You can use https. Please refer to  [Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

Used this command to convert SSH to HTTPS. 
`$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` I was now able to upload the local repository to GitHub after logging in.